# Adding Restkit to project repository

Tags: iphone, repository, restkit

I am having issues adding the restkit framework to my project repository in xCode. I am using a Beanstalk repository and when I added the restKit project to my current project I cannot commit the RestKit project so others can get it that are working on the same project

Comment: Not sure about the Beanstalk repo, but i don't commit the RestKit into our svn - i made a little shell script that pulls all of our required libs from github into proper directories.

Comment: Thanks but got it working. Committed it to my repository using the program cornerstone

Answer (score 0):

You can drag only the library mentioned below, form the Build/Debug-iphoneos[image] of restkit project, instead of moving complete project. you can add these files to your repository
[image]

libRestKitCoreData.a

libRestKitJSONParserNXJSON.a

libRestKitJSONParserSBJSON.a

libRestKitJSONParserYAJL.a

libRestKitNetwork.a

libRestKitObjectMapping.a

libRestKitSupport.a

libRestKitXMLParserLibxml.a